# How to convert an encoded string to a readable format?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I import a mat file with scipy.io.loadmat and one of the variables is a numpy.ndarray of strings  that look like

```
'a\x00\x00\x00cytns\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00cy\x00ie\x00z-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00u\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00z'
```

How to convert them to a readable format in Python3?

Comment: it's a binary representation, so converting it to a readable format would require you to know the encoding used to encode it in this format first

Comment: Where do you want to read the string? Encoding is all about the representation if you print this string in a terminal with `utf8` as it's encoding you'll easily get `acytnsocyiez--utz`.

Comment: @Ayush Shanker How do I find the encoding? I used type(x) it gives me <class 'numpy.str_'>

Comment: @Kasramvd looks like it is not utf8 because acytnsocyiez--utz is something not understandable.

Answer (score 3):

[image: python3 Example]

The **StringIO** module might help in python2.

**Demo:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import StringIO
s = 'a\x00\x00\x00cytns\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00cy\x00ie\x00z-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00u\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00z'
print StringIO.StringIO(s).getvalue()

# using decode method
print s.decode('utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
acytnsocyiez--utz
acytnsocyiez--utz
```

Comment: There is no StringIO in python3. I do: from io import StringIO but StringIO(s).getvalue() gives me the same srting as s -- not decoded

Comment: in python3 use 'from io import StringIO'